# What is the difference between RedisCacheWriter and RedisTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

```
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}
```

---

case 1:  Using RedisCacheWriter

```
public RedisCacheManager getRedisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheWriter cacheWriter = RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    JdkSerializationRedisSerializer jdkSerializer = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(loader);
    SerializationPair<Object> pair = SerializationPair.fromSerializer(jdkSerializer);

    RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfig = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().serializeValuesWith(pair);
    cacheConfig = cacheConfig.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(3600));


    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> initialCacheConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
    initialCacheConfigurations.put("order",cacheConfig.entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(1600)));


    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(cacheWriter, cacheConfig,initialCacheConfigurations);

    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager=getRedisCacheManager(jedisConnectionFactory());
    log.info("CacheManager created ");
    return cacheManager;
}
```

---

case 2:  RedisTemplate

```
@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
CacheManager cacheManager() {

    //JedisConnectionFactory cacheManager=jedisConnectionFactory();
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(60);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);            
    return cacheManager;
}
```

What is the difference between `RedisCacheManager` and `RedisTemplate`? There is a significant memory consumption difference between both the classes. Is it something regarding their internal implementation of storing in cache?
Springboot 2.x is having `RedisCacheWriter` but in Springboot 1.4.3 we have to use `RedisTemplate`.